# Word Count function is picking up "" as a viable word?

Tags: javascript, object

I've written a basic function to count word frequency within a string. First, I split the string into an array, then I iterate through the array of words via for loop. That said, if initial string is empty (""), my function will regard "" as a word and thus the result is {"": 1} rather than an empty object. I initially thought that the empty string wouldn't register at all, due to the for-loop.

I've fixed this issue through an if conditional at the start of the function, but I was wondering if there was a better way to go about it.

```
function countWords(str) {
  if (str === "") {
    return {};  
  }

  var counts = {};
  var wordArray = str.split(" ");
  for (i=0;i < wordArray.length; i++) {

    word = wordArray[i];
    if (!counts[word]) {
      counts[word] = 1;
    } else {
      counts[word] += 1;   
    }
  }
return counts;
}
```

My Ruby code equivalent did not require anything to not pick up the empty string as a viable word target, so this bothers me somewhat.

Edit: Thank you to all the responses. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the situation, but if in your case only strings are passed as parameter that check is good enough.

If there's possibility of `undefined`, `null` or other [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) being passed as a parameter as well, you could do this check instead:

```
if (!str) {
   return {};
}
```

If you want a check even stricter you could do:

```
if (!str || typeof str !== 'string') {
   return {};
}
```

In this case you are checking falsy values(as we saw above empty string is a falsy value) and making sure you are getting as parameter a string.

Comment: I didn't ask this in the original prompt, but I was also wondering why I'd even need the check in the first place. I mean, looking at the for-loop alone, I didn't think it would run at all since i = 0 and the array.length = 0.

Comment: Oh. I get it now. Because I registered it in the array.

Comment: If you try to do a `split` of something that is not a string it is going to fail, so making that check could be good depending on the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. `.split()` does not guarantee non-empty strings in the results. Unless you filter out empty strings explicitly, all empty strings that `.split()` returns will be counted.

Since `.split` does not coalesce sequential split strings, you may have *a lot* of empty strings after split: try `"a   b     c".split(" ")`.

Comment: I came to that conclusion myself after playing with the code a bit. Never the less, thanks for the input. I need to peer through my own work a bit more diligently. Just been finding Javascript somewhat less beginner-friendly compared to Ruby overall.

Comment: No problem. Also, it usually helps (me) to play with small snippets of code in node repl / browser console / jsfiddle, to see how they work with different inouts.